# Meteorjs: value of this in helpers and events

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor so obviously I do not know the Meteor best practice. I am trying to understand the context `this` in a template's helpers and events functions. What I wanted was to tie the text of a div to an input field.

**Coffeescript**

```
Template.test.helpers
    text: "initial text"


Template.test.events
    "keypress #input": (e) ->
        this.text = e.target.value
        return
```

But I've learned that `this` does not point to `test`. What is the right way to access helpers from events?

Also I tried `Tempalte.test.text = e.target.value` though the value is changing, the DOM is not being updated. Aren't helpers supposed to be reactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set helpers that way. If you want it to be reactive the best way is using a Session variable. I don't write coffescript but here's how you can do it with javascript:

```
Template.test.text = function(){
    return Session.get("myTextVar");
};

Template.test.events({
    "keypress #input":function(e,t){
        Session.set("myTexVar",e.target.value);
     }
});
```

You could also create your own reactive variables but that's too hard for that you need.

Comment: for some reason `keypress` event does not fire for final character, so I replaced it with `keyup` and everything works fine. Thanx for the help